# In-build keyboard is dead until restart

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, services, hibernate

I'm on HP Pavillion laptop (HP Pavilion 15-AU030NG) with Windows10 x 64. I'm experiencing a weird behavior of the in-build keyboard since some time:

**Case 1**

If i plug out my usb keyboard, so the in-build laptop PS/2 keyboard remains dead, until i restart the laptop. After restart the in-build keyboard works as expected.

**Case 2** (usb-keyboard is not plugged in)

After the laptop wakes up from energy-saving mode or from hibernation state, the inbuild keyboard remains again dead - until restart. After restart the keyboard is up and riunning.

I suppose as a cause a Windows update, which has killed any service - but i could be wrong with my suppose.

Please point me to probable causes of the problem - specially to Windows services, responsible for în-build keyboard.

**PS**: i activated in the device manager→PS/2 keyboard an option "make waking up by keyboard possible" - no success by this.

Answer (score 0):

See [HP Notebook PCs - Keyboard Troubleshooting (Windows)](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03738933) in *HP Customer Support - Knowledge Base*.

The article provides step-by-step instructions on the topics:

  - Test the Keyboard

  - Pressing keys does nothing (keyboard is not working)

  - ...etc